# Divide List object in two objects with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I have a question...
I need divide a List in two objects, i have the next code:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PersonalData> _PersonalData
    {
        get
        {
            List<PersonalData> listDP = new List<PersonalData>();
            if (PersonalData != null)
            {
                listDP.Add(PersonalData);
            }
            if (InitialsPersonalData != null)
            {
                listDP.Add(InitialsPersonalData);
            }
            return listDP;
        }
        set
        {
            InitialsPersonalData = value.FirstOrDefault(dp => dp.IsInitialData);
            PersonalData = value.FirstOrDefault(dp => !dp.IsInitialData);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public PersonalData InitialsPersonalData { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public PersonalData PersonalData { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalData
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid User_Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public bool IsInitialData { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid User_Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Is possible do that? I am using Lazy Loading. The get method is working but the set method not, never enter in set method. 
 I try use _PersonalData as private and public, with virtual and without virtual... The problem is when i do:

```
dbContext.Users.Where(......)
```

PersonalData and InitialPersonalData always is null, Documents is ok and do authomatically the Include. 
 Can you help me please? What is wrong? Is possible do that? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

`PersonalData` and `InitialPersonalData` are not mapped in the DB, so you cannot use them on DB side.

You need to materialize your data with `dbContext.Users.ToList()` before using them, but this will bring up your entire Users table, and depending on the size, this will slow down your application, if you have any other criteria to filter your table before materializing apply it to improve perfs.

Comment: If i do that, in the Users Table EF created `InitialsPersonalData_Id` and `PersonalData_Id` and i have problems with Cascade Delete... Finally i created another class... Now i have 2 classes `InitialsData` and `PersonalData` i know maybe is not cool... but i cant find another solution... :S ty